# Is there any open source driver for AMD Radeon R5 M430?

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics

According to this Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_graphics_device_driver#ATI.2FAMD), some AMD graphics chips have open source drivers. Better said, there are open source drivers for them.

It is not clear from the article, though, if Radeon R5 M430 falls in this category and has an open source Linux driver developed for it or not. Can anyone help please?

As a side note, as far as I know Intel graphics are now completely available to the FOSS society to write drivers for, NVidia does not show any interest in helping write open source drivers  (see the above article and also this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYWzMvlj2RQ)), but AMD drivers are partially open source.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just trying to figure this out myself, but this is what I've learned.  I think what you want is the at [RadeonFeature](https://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/) page at the X.org foundation. You can find the code name of your chip [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units). The Radeon R4 M430 looks like it's an "Exo Pro" architecture, which doesn't look like it's supported by the open source driver yet.